# Using runas with IE8

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer, runas

We currently run IE6. Our helpdesk people routinely start admin sessions of Windows Explorer by

1. Right-clicking the IE6 shortcut on the quicklaunch bar,
2. Selecting "Run as...",
3. Entering admin account details
4. Browsing to C:\
5. Bingo - admin session to the file system

Now, we're planning an upgrade to IE8. On our test machines, if we try to repeat the above process, everything works until we browse to C:. The Explorer session pops up in a *second* window, but it's not running under an admin session! It's running as the logged on user.

Do our guys just have to learn the cmd runas command and get used to it, or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some good answers, but it's easier than I thought:

Go to the hidden folder `c:\windows\ie8`, and look for iexplore.exe - this should be the IE6 executable. Runas works the 'old' way on this file.

Answer (score 3):

It's about time your guys found, installed, and used [ShellRunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx) from [Microsoft Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx).

All they would then need to do is <kbd>right-click</kbd> on Windows Explorer, and choose <kbd>Run as different user</kbd>

[image: ShellRunAs by Sysinternals]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/cc300361.ShellRunas(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

--->>> runas /user:machine\administrator "explorer.exe /separate"
should work for anyone on WinXP

another option is use A43 File Management Utility [ http://www.alterion.us/a43/]
Just right-click and do a normal RunAs, works fine and gives you access to the same things as normal Explorer does.

Answer (score 0):

On windows xp you can also write:
`runas /user:machine\administrator "explorer.exe /separate`

where you substitute **machine** with actual machine name or domain name and **administrator** with any administrator account.

On Vista this trick does not work since /separate switch isn't supported anymore. You can still use RUNAS, but you need to know the actual path to executable.